# In javascript, how can I tell what object a function is bound to (ie, its 'this') without calling it?

Tags: javascript, function, this

Does anybody know?  Couldn't find this question asked before, even though it seems fairly basic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `context` (the [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/this_Operator) keyword) it's not completely *implicit*, it can be set and changed *explicitly*.

For example:

```
function test () {
  alert(this);
}

test.call("Hello world");
```

The `test` function is called with a string as the context.

So in conclusion, you cannot know what `this` is unless you explicitly define it, or you are inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

The same function will see different values of `this` depending on how it called. See [Crockford](http://javascript.crockford.com/survey.html) for details, but there are four cases:

1. Invoked as a simple function, it is bound to the global/window object.
2. Invoked as a method on an object, it refers to that object.
3. Invoked as a constructor via the `new` keyword, it is the newly instantiated object, which inherits from the object stored in function's own `prototype` property.
4. Invoked by its own `apply` or `call` method, it is the first argument supplied.

If these cases sound complex, tedious, and error-prone, all the more reason to avoid relying on `this` outside of methods, where it makes the most sense anyway.